# Alternative to onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle), for save data when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-orientation

When I change orientation from portrait to landscape, then the data gets lost.
I know that the oncreate gets called again and all is lost.

And I know to save the data I have put the data in Bundle in **onSaveInstanceState()** method and get the data in **onRestoreInstanceState()** method.
For example like here: [Example!!](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/)

But it's really annoying and time intense.

Is it not possible to change orientation, without losing the data?

Comment: *But it's really annoying and time intense.*, what and why ?

Comment: because I have to put all data in the bundle and retrieve it again. Again have to see if for example the state of the bluetooth connect is true, and set the color of a button again if it's true, and so on.

Comment: imo, you are trying to solve a not-a-problem. Did you experienced performance  issues?

Comment: No, but I find this really stupid that the data gets lost on orientation change. I cant understand why the android system throws the data. it just have to change the layout for the orientation.

Comment: It does not trows the data. It throws away the current instance of the class/activity you have at screen.

Comment: yes but why can't it be restored automatically from the system, when orientation changes?

Comment: the system has not knowledge of your data.

Comment: make your data static

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SharedPreferences and save the data in there and when orientation occurs then you get data on it. You follow the tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).

But I dont really recommend using it just on orientation change. OnSaveIntance would be preferable than SharedPreferences on orientation change, but since you ask what is the other.

Comment: It's the same. There is no improvment.

Comment: @aut_silvia did you implement it??

Comment: Look the comment on my question, i think that explains why I ask this question.

Comment: not all information you want to save. next time you start the app maybe you want to start from scratch. if saving status in shared preferences how to distinguish between just rotating and starting the app ? to use shared preferences for this is definitely NOT the recommended way. and i agree to make an app "rotate-able" has sometimes a big effort. therefore locking the screen for rotation is sometimes an easier programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

I, add configChanges to the activity in your manisfest file:

```
<activity>
     android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
     ...
```

Check this for more details on `configChanges`:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html